# Superclass of String (or T) and Enum

Tags: java, enums

I have some small logging system and it can process `String`s, which is all working fine.
Now I want to add the ability to signal that I want a new line, and due to my structure I think it is best to use a special flag, some example code:

```
public class BaseLogger implements Runnable, LogConsumer {
    //....
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    //....

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (running) {
            try {
                if (consumers.isEmpty()) {
                    synchronized(consumersEmptyLock) {
                        consumersEmptyLock.wait();
                    }
                }
                String message = queue.take();
                for (LogConsumer consumer : consumers) {
                    consumer.consume(message);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                handleInterrupt();
            }
            if (requestShutdown && queue.isEmpty()) {
                running = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void log(String message) {
        if (message == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("customlogger.CustomLogger.log: message == null");
        }
        queue.offer(message);
    }
```

So now I want to add an enum, let's say `LogFlagEnum`, which includes a flag called `NEW_LINE`.

However currently my `queue` is of type `String`, and I would like it to include both `String` (or perhaps `T` for a more general answer) and `LogFlagEnum`.

I know I could use `Object` as type, but that is not the smallest possible type and definatey not safe and what I want.

What would be the best way to implement the specified behaviour?

Comment: The only common super class of String and Enum is java.lang.Object. Do you really want to mix types? If so then you should again think over the design and the use of generics.

Comment: Have a queue of `Message` and use the `toString` method to log. Or add a literal new line - `System.lineSeparator()` - to the queue.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I thought/hoped it could be done by using `Class<T>`, where `T` is *some* definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: use Object. It's no big deal since it's just internal implementation.

Solution 2: use CharSequence; have the enum implement CharSequence. Not exactly very helpful. But in general CharSequence is better than String for accepting text arguments.

Solution 3: every problem in Java can be solved by introducing a new type. You queue can be a queue of `LogEntry`'s, and `LogEntry` can contain String/enum/whatever.

Comment: `LogEntry` consisting of `String message` and `LogFlag flag` might be the best solution?

Comment: yeah. or you can have StringLogEntry and FlagLogEntry. and it is a slippery slope leading to a java architect career.